# initializationError in GWT TestCase Execution

Tags: gwt, junit, gwt-maven-plugin, gwttestcase

I created a project with default module in GWT with maven. and renamed the Test Case class with *Test.java and executed the command **mvn package**

It is not successfully executing the test case, and terminates with 
**Tests in error:
  initializationError(com.gwt.example.project.testing.client.GwtTesttestingTest): com/google/gwt/dev/cfg/Condition.**

if i add, `<mode>htmlunit</mode>` and `<htmlunit>IE7</htmlunit>` to pom and then `gwt:test` goal works fine

If i try to execute the test case in eclipse by right click and run as GWT Junit Test, it keeps on executing without stopping,

this is what the output while executing test case in eclipse.

```
Validating newly compiled units
   Ignored 12 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
Starting http://10.1.1.2:57354/com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=10.1.1.2:57348 on browser FF3
200 - GET /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=10.1.1.2:57348 (10.1.1.2) 2449 bytes
logging for HtmlUnit thread
   [WARN] Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://10.1.1.2:57354/com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit.nocache.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
200 - GET /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit.nocache.js (10.1.1.2) 6344 bytes
200 - GET /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/hosted.html?com_gwt_example_project_testing_testingJUnit_JUnit (10.1.1.2) 11757 bytes
200 - GET /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/gwt/standard/standard.css (10.1.1.2) 26953 bytes
Validating newly compiled units
   Ignored 12 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
Module com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit has been loaded
200 - POST /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junithost (10.1.1.2) 434 bytes
All clients connected (Limiting future permutations to: gecko1_8)
200 - POST /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junithost (10.1.1.2) 434 bytes
[WARN] Too many clients: expected 1, found 2
200 - POST /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junithost (10.1.1.2) 434 bytes
[WARN] Too many clients: expected 1, found 3
200 - POST /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junithost (10.1.1.2) 434 bytes
[WARN] Too many clients: expected 1, found 4
200 - POST /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junithost (10.1.1.2) 434 bytes
[WARN] Too many clients: expected 1, found 5
200 - POST /com.gwt.example.project.testing.testingJUnit.JUnit/junithost (10.1.1.2) 434 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at a lightweight project here: https://github.com/fastnsilver/gwt-datehandling-example

that runs a single `GWTTestCase` via a suite.

Some profiles are defined, so have a look at the README. Most of what's in the Maven pom.xml for bootstrapping GWT tests was taken straight from documentation.